# what happens to uncovered Bokashi waste?

Tags: pests, compost

Usually Bokashi waste is advised to be buried.

But we know rats are not attracted to the Bokashi waste. So what is the real reason for burying this waste. What happens if Bokashi waste is not buried?

Note: Being left on soil without burying it will expose the waste to even more oxygen while they are still in touch with the required soil bacteria.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be buried because the Bokashi method is not a complete composting process, only a pre composting one. Burying in soil completes the process. Some ways to achieve that here  https://bokashiliving.com/what-do-i-do-with-my-pre-compost/

The Bokashi method is usually used indoors for composting kitchen scraps, which can include meat, bones, fish, dairy etc. Partially fermented Bokashi compost just left on open ground outdoors unburied will attract wasps, flies and other insects, along with rats, cats, dogs and any other wildlife around. That's the other reason to bury it.

Comment: My question is what is wrong with just dropping it on the soil but not burying it? It still is in touch with bacteria and even more oxygen. But what is wrong with it?

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: It has become even more complicated. How come buried Bokashi waste does not attract rats but the unburied one attracts? For the normal composted meats we know that even the buried ones will attract rats.

Comment: If you just want to put it on the soil, try it, see what happens...or bury half and put half on the soil as an experiment.